# Windows App with Azure App Services for Mobile Apps

Tags: windows, sqlite, azure, mbaas, azure-app-service-plans

I am builing a Windows Phone Store App at the moment and I am planning to build a Windows Store App in the future (Universal Windows App). I want to synchronize the items stored in the local SQLite database with a remote database and between the  different platforms (Windows Phone, Windows, ...).

So, I did a few searches about mobile backends and I ended up at [Microsoft Azure App Services for Mobile](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-preview/) with [offline sync](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-preview/). Before I start, I want to clarify some important questions for me.

1. I have different users which will authenticate via Facebook, Microsoft Account, etc. How will the different entries be distinguished for each user? Do I have to add an userId property on each table and select only entries with relation to the userId?
2. I am currently using the NuGet package sqlite-net with sqlite-net extensions for support of relationships like One-to-Many, Many-to-Many, etc. Azure Mobile Apps seems to support only simple objects and I have to manage the relationship via a foreign key manually.
3. How much will Microsoft Azure App Services for Mobile Apps cost for a few thousands user, if I only use the remote database with offline sync?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure this is the correct way but yes. Then you can customize the PullAsync to return only records that relate to a specified user (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/181).
2. Yes. Currently it does not support relations for the client SQLite database. You have to do it manually in your client. Have a look at Adrian's answer here: ([Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps with Views or Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840116/offline-data-sync-in-azure-mobile-apps-with-views-or-stored-procedure))
3. It depends on your data and the database type. If you are using Azure SQL Server, a basic plan with a monthly fee of ($5 to $10) may be good to go. And for the Azure Mobile App you can start the free plan.